# How to use Matplotlib rcParams with Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm writing a custom matplotlib stylesheet for my company. Among other things I'm trying to change the colors of the boxplot lines. The following example changes the `rcParams` using a dictionary. The standard plot built using matplotlib has the right colors, while it seems that only some parameters are changed in the seaborn plot. How can I force seaborn to use my stylesheet?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_penguins = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/penguins.csv"
)
ex = {
        'boxplot.boxprops.color': 'hotpink',
        'boxplot.notch': True,
        'boxplot.patchartist': False,
        'boxplot.showbox': True,
        'boxplot.showcaps': True,
        'boxplot.showfliers': True,
        'boxplot.showmeans': False,
        'boxplot.vertical': True,
        'boxplot.whiskerprops.color': 'hotpink',
        'boxplot.whiskerprops.linestyle': '--',
        'boxplot.whiskerprops.linewidth': 1.0,
        'boxplot.whiskers': 1.5,
    }

plt.rcParams.update(**ex)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(
    ncols=2, 
    sharey=True,
    figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5)
)
sns.boxplot(data=df_penguins, y="body_mass_g", ax=ax1)

ax2.boxplot(df_penguins.body_mass_g.dropna())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: seaborn boxplots generally don't read from the matplotlib rcparams (otherwise they would not look different by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different from @mwaskom 's comment *Seaborn* does use `matplotlib`'s `rcParams` under the hood.

By default you activate the seaborn default them via `sns.set_theme()` which has a direct effect on `rcParams`. You can overwrite the defaults using the `rc` argument in that function.

Sidenote: It is possible but not recommended to mix `matplotlib` and `seaborn` imports. In short: Don't import `matplotlib` when importing `seaborn`.

I updated your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_penguins = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/penguins.csv"
)
ex = {
        'boxplot.boxprops.color': 'hotpink',
        'boxplot.notch': True,
        'boxplot.patchartist': False,
        'boxplot.showbox': True,
        'boxplot.showcaps': True,
        'boxplot.showfliers': True,
        'boxplot.showmeans': False,
        'boxplot.vertical': True,
        'boxplot.whiskerprops.color': 'hotpink',
        'boxplot.whiskerprops.linestyle': '--',
        'boxplot.whiskerprops.linewidth': 1.0,
        'boxplot.whiskers': 1.5,
    }

# This loads the Seaborn default theme settings
# and overwrites them with your values from "ex"
sns.set_theme(rc=ex)

plot = sns.boxplot(data=df_penguins, y="body_mass_g")
plot.figure.show()
```

[image]

Be aware that not all of your settings from `ex` do have an effect here. For example, the `hotpink`. But I'm sure this is not a problem with my solution. For example `boxplot.notch` does work.

So I'm sorry that this only answers how to modify the `rcParams` via Seaborn but not how to modify specific aspects of your theme.